# Why isn't T[string] a valid object lookup type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to better understand how lookup types work in TypeScript.

I have seen T[number] used as a lookup type that gives a union, like follows:

```
type Tuple = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
type TupleToUnion = Tuple[number]
// gives union type: 'cat' | 'dog' | 'elephant'
```

I wanted to use T[string] to do a similar lookup on an object type. The result is not successful:

```
type Obj = { 'cat': 'cat', 'dog': 'dog', 'elephant': 'elephant' }
type ObjToUnion = Obj[string]
// Type 'Obj' has no matching index signature for type 'string'. (2537)
```

Why does T[number] work as a lookup type and T[string] does not?

Comment: You can use `type ObjToUnion = Obj[keyof Obj]` in the second example to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

An array type has an interface similar to this:

```
interface ArrayLike<T> {
  length: number;
  [key: number]: T;
}
```

Therefore, `ArrayType[number]` is correct because the interface specified that all keys will be number type.

For a custom object type, like the one you use in example:

```
type Obj = {
  'cat': 'cat';
  'dog': 'dog';
  'elephant': 'elephant'
}
```

While all keys are indeed of string type, only 3 specific string keys are valid: `cat`, `dog`, `elephant`. Therefore, doing `Obj[string]` is wrong because `string` represents *all* string values (like `abc`, `hello`, etc), not just the 3 keys.

To use `Obj[string]`, you would need to declare it the way similar to ArrayLike:

```
type Obj = {
  [key: string]: string;
}

type ObjToUnion = Obj[string]; // ok
```

To get only the keys from an object, you can use [`keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html):

```
type Obj = {
  'cat': 'cat';
  'dog': 'dog';
  'elephant': 'elephant'
}

type ObjToUnion = Obj[keyof Obj];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwLACgpQOQDGAhsHgFz7GkDc2ueAJgPYDm5+zbtO+EANhDAALIgDtSFPP0EjxebAF9s2UJFiIAKkwCqogJZNRKdQgDaAawggmAMxMBdIA)

**EDIT**

This is called index signature. Its documentation can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

Comment: You might want to provide a link to the documentation for [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), since the issue here is whether or not a type has a `string` / `number` index signature.